# Use SVG foreignObject Tag in Angular7

Tags: angular, svg

In angular 7,I want to user the SVG foreignObject to insert some HTML code.But it is not working.The terminal report an error.The angular fail to identify the HTML tag

#### This is the code

```html
<g id="peizhi" (click)="config()" style="width: 110px; height: 30px" transform="translate(181,0)">
<!--      <a (click)="config()" style="width: 110px;height: 30px">-->
        <use xlink:href="#Rectangle" x="0" y="0"></use>
        <text x="15" y="10" style="fill: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);width: 24px;height: 27px;" font-size="12px">
          配置
        </text>
        <polygon  points="41 0, 47 0, 44 4" fill="rgba(216, 216, 216, 1)"/>

      <foreignObject width="100" height="50"
                     requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
        <!-- XHTML content goes here -->
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
<!--      </a>-->
    </g>
```

#### This is the error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
':svg:p' is not a known element:
1. If ':svg:p' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("     <!-- XHTML content goes here -->
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        [ERROR ->]<p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
"): ng:///OperateNavModule/EndmonitorNavComponent.html@49:8
':svg:body' is not a known element:
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the xhtml namespace to the paragraph. Like this:

```
<xhtml:p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
```

You can try it out [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/dbaAepyUm99pU4oS?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview).

Answer (score 3):

```
<ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
  <svg:g class="node">
    <svg:foreignObject>
      <div>Your HTML here</div>
    </svg:foreignObject>
  </svg:g>
</ng-template>
```

OR

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow"/>
  <foreignObject  x="10" y="10" width="100px" height="50px" >
    <xhtml:div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background-color: aqua;">
      foreign object
    </xhtml:div> 
  </foreignObject> 
</svg>
```

Like this we can use foreigObject in angular

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Similar solution if anyone is using d3 to draw the elements, `ele.append("xhtml:div")` will do the work.